# Is setting high mismatch and gap penalties sufficient to distinguish perfectly mapping reads?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I have a fat pile of 125bp whole genome shotgun reads that have undergone quality control, and I would like to pull out just those reads that *do not* map perfectly to the genome. When I set extremely high penalties for mismatches and gap opens/extensions (with `bwa mem -B 1000 -O [1000,1000] -E [1000,1000]`), it ***looks like*** the alignments for perfectly mapping reads are shown, and the rest of the reads are reported as unmapped. If this is true, I could then pull out the unmapped reads with `samtools -f 4`.

Are there any holes in my reasoning here, or will it work to discard all of the reads that map perfectly to the genome?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**: No, setting extremely high penalties (100 or 1000) does not seem to work. I'm not sure why.

**The medium answer**: Since I posted the question, I did a bit of exploring, and it looks like the reads that perfectly match are the reads that are not soft clipped and that have an edit distance of zero, as indicated by the CIGAR string and NM tag, respectively.

**The long answer**: See https://standage.github.io/how-to-distinguish-perfectly-mapped-reads-from-a-sambam-file.html.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way is to map normally and then filter out imperfect matches downstream:

```
bwa mem ref.fa reads.fq | perl -ane 'print if /^@/ || ($F[5]=~/^\d+M$/ && /\tNM:i:0/)'
```

Changing the scoring scheme hurts mapping accuracy.

Comment: "Changing the scoring scheme hurts mapping accuracy." This is a concern if you want to keep all of the alignments around for other purposes, but is a non-issue if I **only** want to distinguish perfectly mapped reads vs imperfectly mapped.

Comment: I used to consider myself quite the Perl-slinger (I code mostly in Python these days), but I never knew about the `-a` flag. That's a game changer! +1